# Getting extra cell in the header of a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm having a small problem with an ASP GridView.  Below is the HTML:

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvSDS" runat="server" Visible="False" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="4" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="gvSDS_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SDSID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" ShowHeader="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SKU" HeaderText="SKU #" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ManName" HeaderText="Manufacturer" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfExpiry" HeaderText="Date Of Expiry" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNum" HeaderText="Phone #" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Languages" HeaderText="Languages" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="" Text="Edit" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" ImageURL="../../Content/Images/edit.png"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsActive" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnActive" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="" Text="Make Inactive" OnClick="btnActive_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnArchive" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="" Text="Archive" OnClick="btnArchive_Click" ImageURL="../../Content/Images/delete.png" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
```

This is producing the following output:

[image: Image of table]

Circled in yellow is my problem.  On the header row there is an extra column and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That one is supposed to be there. But for some reason looks like your edit is inside of your Languages cell O.O. Looks like you have another BoundField snuck in there too.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="IsActive" />
```